# is there a remote version of KDirStat

Tags: linux, disk-utility

I love KDirStat (or equivalent) but I would like to be able to run it on remote host (which doesn't have X11 installed). Is there anything avaible (and free) which will allow me to get a treemap of the disk usage remotely (Ideally on a webbrowser ) ?

Answer (score 3):

Use the **qdirstat-cache-writer** or **kdirstat-cache** **writer** Perl script on your server, copy the file to your desktop machine and view it there with **QDirStat / KDirStat**.

See also

https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat
https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat/tree/master/scripts

-- HuHa (KDirStat / QDirStat author)

Comment: Detailed description now available here: https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat/blob/master/doc/QDirStat-for-Servers.md

Answer (score 2):

I found a nice script [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040923034351201) that can do what you need. There was a bug in the original script which I corrected, you can download my corrected version from [here](http://pastebin.com/PQqvgHwz). So, log on to the remote server and run these commands:

1. Download the script

   ```
   curl -o duHTMLtree 'http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=PQqvgHwz'
   ```
2. Make it executable

   ```
   chmod a+x duHTMLtree
   ```
3. Use `du` (a standard *ix program) to create directory size data. I will use the `/usr` directory as an example, change it as appropriate.

   ```
   du -k /usr > usr.txt
   ```
4. Run the script to create html output showing files of >50M.

   ```
   ./duHTMLtree -s50M '-tMy Disk Tree' -n'My Disk' -c1 usr.txt > usr.html
   ```
5. As long as the file `usr.html` is accessible from the internet, you can access it in your browser. You can see examples of the output at the script's original site [here](http://www.studiosells.net/msells/duHTMLtree/sample1.html) and [here](http://www.studiosells.net/msells/duHTMLtree/sample2.html).

For more information and documentation on the script's usage, see the original author's [site](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040923034351201).

Answer (score 0):

One web-based option would be `Philesight`, which is a graphical disk usage solution that works in your browser.

http://zevv.nl/play/code/philesight/

You could also mount the remote machine's filesystem locally to be able to use your kdirstat.  If you are using a windows machine as your local workstation then mounting the filesystem locally would not be ideal since you can't run `kdirstat` on windows.

Another option would be to use an application called `baobab` which is gtk based.  It's more lightweight that `kdirstat` so the system requirements would be lower to install it on the remote machine but would still need some base X11 libraries.

Comment: I guess I X11 installed on the remote machine to be able to install KDirStat, that's not a option. I'm looking for an alternative to KDirStat.

Comment: @mb14, what is your local machine's operating system?

Comment: @mb14, I added a web-based solution to my answer that will work regardless of your local machine's operating system.

Comment: debian-squeeze. I'll have alook a philesight